# How can I Filter Computers by Site ID in a Vuex getter

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm building an app that will present the user with a list of sites, once the user has clicked on a site all of the computers present at that site will display, and then a user can click on a computer to get the details for that machine.

I've successfully used `Axios` to consume our API of sites and computers, i have also setup `vue-router` to generate the routes and im using `vuex` as the store. I can display the entire list of computers in the site component, but now I need to filter the computers so that only computers whose `computer.site` match `site.id`.

I'm new to `vue.js` and `vuex` so this is a challenge for me. I think I just need a push in the right direction and I can get over this hurdle. My goal is to re-use this type of filter for other logic as well as Alerts that match a `site.id` etc.

I'm not sure where to start with this, so here I am.

Here is my **store.js** file.

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
import axios from "axios";

Vue.use(Vuex, axios);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    sites: [],
    computers: []
  },
  actions: {
    // SITES
    getSites({commit}) {
      axios
        .get("/sites/read.php", {})
        .then(response => {
          let sites = response.data.data;
          commit("SET_SITES", sites);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          // eslint-disable-next-line
          console.log(error);
        });
    },
    // SITES
    getComputers({commit}) {
      axios
        .get("/sshtunnels/read.php", {})
        .then(response => {
          let computers = response.data.data;
          commit("SET_COMPUTERS", computers);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          // eslint-disable-next-line
          console.log(error);
        });
    }
  },
  getters: {
    siteData: state => state.sites,
    // need to change this to filter to only have computers that match the current site id
    // Can we derive the current id from this.$route.params.siteID?
    computerData: state => state.computers,
    //something like this?
    getComputerbyID: (state, id) => (id) => {
      return state.computers.find(computer => computer.Site === site.id)
    }

  },
  mutations: {
    SET_SITES(state, sites) {
      state.sites = sites;
    },
    SET_COMPUTERS(state, computers) {
      state.computers = computers;
    }
  }
});
```

**computed props :**

```js
computed: {
  sites() {
    return this.$store.getters.siteData;
  },
  computers() {
    return this.$store.getters.computerData;
  }
}
```

I'd expect to have the output of `{{ computer.hostname }}` filtered to only show computers whose ID match the Site ID.

Thanks everyone!

UPDATE

Thanks for your input, however I get an error

```
Property or method "siteId" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.
```

Its true that I don't have a property called siteID. I do have site.ID in the sites array. But that doesn't appear to work either as I cant use site.ID in the fat arrow function.

This does not work

```
getComputersBySiteId: (state) => (site.id) => {
      return state.computers.filter(computer => computer.Site === site.id);
```

Do I need to add a let id = site.id somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

First off create a [Vuex getter with params](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#method-style-access).

```
getComputersBySiteId: (state) => (id) => {
   return state.computers.filter(computer => computer.siteId === id);
}
```

Then consume it in component like this: `const computers = this.$store.getters.getComputersById(siteId);`

Or using [`mapGetters`](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#the-mapgetters-helper) helper.

```
import { mapGetters } from "vuex";

computed: {
  ...mapGetters(["getComputersBySiteId"])
}
```

Then in template:

```html
<ul>
  <li v-for="computer in getComputersBySiteId(siteId)" :key="computer.id">
    {{ computer.name }}
  </li>
</ul
```

Comment: I'd say unless OP needs to share the current filter across components, there's no need to place it on Vuex. I'd put the filter in a `computed`.

Comment: For this particular component (SingleSite.vue) I only need to display the computers that have a computer.site === site.id I would like to reuse the functionality as I will need to have a similar filter when I go to the individual computer level. ie. only show me details of the particular computer by id.

I'd love to see how you would build that filter in the component please.

Comment: Just pass to `getComputersBySiteId(siteId)` your site id.

Comment: Sorry, I am a bit daft here. @Javas, how is siteID being determined in your comment? Take a look at my update to the original post. I realize you are volunteering your energy here, but could I ask you to expand your code to include where and when it gets passed? Thanks!